# О случае спискового включения над несколькими списками

Tags: python, функции, int

Любая определённая функция, к примеру:

```
def sum(x,y):
    sume = 0
    x = 0
    x += (x[i] - x[i-1])**2 
    y = 0
    y += (y[i] - y[i-1])**2
    sume = (x+y)**0.5
    return sume
```

а теперь я хочу применить её на массивы обеих переменных. не придумал ничего лучше, как:

```
[sum(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

где х и у:

```
x = random.randint(5,100)
y = random.randint(5,100)
```

вывод сообщает, что 'int' object is not iterable. Я подумал, что причина в том, что локальные и глобальные одним именем (в функции локальные действительно int). Но переименование действия не возымело. Сам подход не верен? спасибо

Comment: Вы хотите двумерный массив сгенерировать?

Comment: зачем двухмерный? одномерный, просто список цифр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно, вы передали в zip числа в качестве аргументов, что не соответствует его сигнатуре

Полагаю, вы хотели передать туда что-то такое:

```
x = range(random.randint(5,100))
y = range(random.randint(5,100))
```

Comment: но теперь не работает индексация: видимо, я неправильно говорю питону посчитать разницу между двумя соседними элементами: ````x += (x[i] - x[i-1])**2 ````